# 3D distortion in Flash

Tags: flash, 3d

I'm making simple 3D transformations in Flash to rotate stuff, but I get distortions. I can rotation left, right, up, down, but not diagonally since it completely distorts my faces (the ones I draw).

I think I fail to move the camera somehow, but I'm not experienced enough to understand my error.

Here's the file: http://www.2shared.com/video/J7ahd6VG/final.html

Example: when a face is rotated at about 45° around the *y* axis (vertical to screen) and then rotated around the *x* axis the perspective doesn't feel right... the faces are too narrow.

[image: Face with should be wider IMO]

What I do is multiply the rotation matrices between themselves (the mouse position providing the angles) get the transformed points, project them to screen and draw boxes with them.

I used this tutorial to get me started: http://bgstaal.net/blog/?p=57

Has anybody encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution: do not directly modify the variables when operating with matrices (eg: **p.x** = a[0]*p.x+a[1]*p.y+p.u*a[2]), otherwise all subsequent values after the first will be erroneous.

Comment: +1, I like the solution :) Also, I think you can answer your own question and accept that one, if you really found the solution for your problem.

Comment: @Solenoid I agree that **you should accept your own answer**. Otherwise it's misleading to passers-by. PS **Congrats** on finding the answer your self!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my own comment below the question for the answer, PEBKAC as usual.